# block the [channel] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup, tag-blacklist-request

The [channel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/channel) tag is a useless meta-tag: this tag does not add any useful meaning by itself, it requires other tags to provide context. That's not how our tags are supposed to be used.

[channel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/channel) has 0 watchers.

There is no [channel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/channel) tag wiki to define what a "channel" is. In fact the word **channel** has different technical meanings in several different contexts, as can be seen from the wide variety of [questions tagged channel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/channel)

- In a MOSFET, the channel is a physical region between drain and source, where conduction happens
- In an ADC (Analog to Digital Converter), a channel is an input signal path
- In a DAC (Digital to Analog Converter), a channel is an output signal path
- Op amps, multiplexers, etc. sometimes the word channel is used to name a signal path
- A band of frequencies in a modulated radio communications spectrum may be divided into sub-units called channels (frequency division multiplexing, time division multiplexing, etc.)
- A baseband communications signal path may also be called a communications channel
- The term "channel interleaving" is seen in DRAM memory architecture
- Sometimes sales/marketing refers to the "distribution channel" i.e. selling parts through a 3rd party distributor like Avnet/Digikey/Farnell/Mouser/Newark
- When I saw the instagram photo of the *Ever Given* lodged in the Suez at an acute angle, I needed to channel my frustration into something productive (*sorry, I couldn't resist*)

Just quickly scrolling through the (currently 60) questions tagged [channel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/channel), I didn't see any questions where [channel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/channel) was the only tag. So it should be safe to bulk delete the tag.

As usual for mass tag edits, we should edit only a few at a time to avoid spamming the "active questions" feed. I'll hold off doing anything until I get some feedback from the *meta channel*...

Comment: I agree that the channel tag is to 'meta' (meaning that it is to broad/overreaching). There is no 'bulk deletion' of tags, we have to go through question by question and remove each tag then after that process is done, we contact a CM to get the tag blacklisted.

Comment: The tag is cleaned, could we get it blacklisted? (as of 4-27 it still can be used)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If someone wants an answer to upvote:

Nuke it.

Answer (score 2):

If I could get help cleaning up the channel tag I would appreciate it, once the tag is removed I'll have a CM look at it.

Edit:
The tag has been cleaned: Could we get a CM to blacklist this tag?

Comment: Should be ready to go now.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, there aren't any new questions with this tag in the months since it was removed - if that's not the case, please let me know. Considering that, I don't see a reason for this tag to be blocked from re-creation. In general, we only block tags that have been burninated and returned more than once.

As such, I'm removing the status tag. Please feel free to retag this as status review in the future if the tag gets created again - hopefully the requirement to have [300 reputation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) before creating tags will reduce the likelihood of that happening.